# Best way to assign key-value pairs to a dictionary from 2 arrays in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

```
    Dictionary<long, long> test = new Dictionary<long, long>();

    long[] keyArray= new long[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    long[] valueArray= new long[] { 4, 3, 2, 1 };
```

**Question 1:**

I tried

```
    for (var i = 0; i < keyArray.Length; i++)
    {
        test.Add(new KeyValuePair<long, long>(keyArray[i], valueArray[i]));
    }
```

But, I get

`There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'value' of 'Dictionary<long, long>.Add(long, long)'`

I couldn't figure out why.

**Question 2**
How to make these assignments more scalable? For example, my arrays can be much bigger. Would the same method be logical for that case?

Comment: What do you mean by "scalable"? How many items do you anticipate? Have you tried if there are any actual issues with performance?

Comment: Regarding Q2: it is then useful to specify a initial capacity using this [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-dictionary-2-ctor(system-int32)). This avoids potentially costly dictionary resizing operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.Add(TKey, TValue)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.add?view=net-6.0) requires 2 parameters first being key, second being value, not one `KeyValuePair`, so you need to change your code slightly:

```
for (var i = 0; i < keyArray.Length; i++)
{
    test.Add(keyArray[i], valueArray[i]);
}
```

Note that `Add` will throw in case if you will try to add an already existing key. If you anticipate duplicate keys and it is ok to silently overwrite value with later one you can just use [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/):

```
for (var i = 0; i < keyArray.Length; i++)
{
    test[keyArray[i]] = valueArray[i];
}
```